# empty div not getting recognised in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

i am creating an empty div in the javascript DOM. but when i call some function on it, for example,

```
    var hover = document.createElement("div");
    hover.className = "hover";
    overlay.appendChild(hover);
    hover.onClick = alert("hi");
```

the onClick function isn't working. Instead it displays an alert as soon as it reaches the div creation part of the script.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [addEventHandler & attachEvent](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) to attach event to an element :

```
if (hover.addEventListener)
{
    // addEventHandler Sample :
    hover.addEventListener('click',function () {
        alert("hi");
    },false);
}
else if (hover.attachEvent)
{
    // attachEvent sample : 
    hover.attachEvent('onclick',function () {
        alert("hi");
    });
}
else
{
    hover.onclick = function () { alert("hi"); };
}
```

Comment: This will only work in browsers that comply with the W3C event model. For IE you'll have to use attachEvent..

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the onclick in a function, something like this:

```
hover.onclick = function() {
   alert('hi!');
}
```

Comment: this has solved the problem somewhat. but now the alert doesnt even gets displayed even upon clicking on the hover area.
to be more informative, the hover is an empty div. and the css class definition:
.hover {
 width: 320px;
 height: 75px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 28%;
 top:32%;
 z-index: 9999;
 background-color: #000;
 overflow: hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

The property name is "onclick" not "onClick". JavaScript is case sensitive.

It also takes a function. The return value of alert(someString) is not a function.